# Create Azure IaaS Domain Controller using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm attempting to add a domain controller to an existing domain using terraform (in Azure). I declared some local values in the main terraform file for my servers, like so:

```
locals {
  username_command = "$username = ${var.domainAdminUsername}"
  password_command = "$password = ConvertTo-SecureString ${var.domainAdminPassword} -AsPlainText -Force"
  credentials_command  = "$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username,$password)"
  install_ad_command   = "Add-WindowsFeature -name ad-domain-services -IncludeManagementTools"
  configure_ad_command = "Install-ADDSDomainController -DomainName ${var.domainName} -InstallDns -Credential $credentials -SafeModeAdministratorPassword $password -Force:$true"
  shutdown_command     = "shutdown -r -t 10"
  exit_code_hack       = "exit 0"
  powershell_command   = "${local.username_command}; ${local.password_command}; ${local.credentials_command}; ${local.install_ad_command}; ${local.configure_ad_command}; ${local.shutdown_command}; ${local.exit_code_hack}"


}
```

I'm then applying a custom script extension resource on the VM, that run the powershell cmdlets built by the local values:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "promote-to-domain-controller" {
  count = 2
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm
  ]

  name                 = "promote-to-domain-controller"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm[count.index].id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -Command \"${local.powershell_command}\""
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

Everything seems to work, but the VM extension. `[ { "code": "ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded", "level": "Info", "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded", "message": "" }, { "code": "ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded", "level": "Info", "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded", "message": "azadmin : The term 'azadmin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. \r\nCheck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.\r\nAt line:1 char:13\r\n+ $username = azadmin; $password = ConvertTo-SecureString <redacted>...\r\n+             ~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (azadmin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException\r\n \r\nNew-Object : Exception calling \".ctor\" with \"2\" argument(s): \"Cannot process argument because the value of argument \r\n\"userName\" is not valid. Change the value of the \"userName\" argument and run the operation again.\"\r\nAt line:1 char:118\r\n+ ... edentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCrede ...\r\n+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand\r\n \r\n" } ]`

var.domainAdminUsername is set to 'azadmin'. In the first screenshot, on line 11, you can see that I'm passing this value ($username) to the PSCredential constructor. This constructor takes two overloads: a string and a securestring. It's like the value that's getting passed to the constructor isn't a string, though it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to promote your VM as a domain controller for a exisitng forest .

**Main.tf file:**

```
   provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
locals {
  password_command = "$password = ConvertTo-SecureString ${var.admin_password} -AsPlainText -Force"

  credentials_command  = "$credentials = Get-Credential ${var.domainAdminUsername}"
  install_ad_command   = "Add-WindowsFeature -name ad-domain-services -IncludeManagementTools"
  configure_ad_command = "Install-ADDSDomainController -DomainName ${var.active_directory_domain} -InstallDns -Credential $credentials -SafeModeAdministratorPassword $password -Force:$true"
  shutdown_command     = "shutdown -r -t 10"
  exit_code_hack       = "exit 0"
  powershell_command   = " ${local.password_command};${local.credentials_command}; ${local.install_ad_command}; ${local.configure_ad_command}; ${local.shutdown_command}; ${local.exit_code_hack}"

}

data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
 name = "${var.vmname}"
 resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "promote-to-domain-controller" {
  name                 = "promote-to-domain-controller"
   virtual_machine_id = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -Command \"${local.powershell_command}\""
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

**variable.tf file:**

```
variable resource_group_name {
  description = "The name of the Resource Group where the VM is"
  default = "resourcegroup"
}
variable location {
  description = "The Azure Region in which the Resource Group exists"
  default = "resourcegrouplocation"
}

# Active Directory & Domain Controller
variable vmname {
  description = "The Virtual Machine name that you wish to join to the domain"
  default = "vmname"
}

variable "active_directory_domain" {
  description = "The name of the Active Directory domain, for example `consoto.local`"
  default = "domainname"
}
variable "domainAdminUsername" {
    description = "The local administrator account on the Domain"
    default = "Domain\admin or admin@domain.com"
}

variable "admin_password" {
  description = "The password associated with the local administrator account on the virtual machine"
  default = "password"
}
```

**Output:** (Terraform Plan)

[image]

**Adding VM to existing domain:**

**Main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "join-domain" {
  name                 = "join-domain"
  location             = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${var.vmname}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "JsonADDomainExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.3"
  

  
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "Name": "${var.active_directory_domain}",
        "OUPath": "",
        "User": "${var.active_directory_domain}\\${var.active_directory_username}",
        "Restart": "true",
        "Options": "3"
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "Password": "${var.active_directory_password}"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

**Variable.tf**

```
variable resource_group_name {
  description = "The name of the Resource Group where the VM is"
}
variable location {
  description = "The Azure Region in which the Resource Group exists"
}

# Active Directory & Domain Controller
variable vmname {
  description = "The Virtual Machine name that you wish to join to the domain"
}

variable "active_directory_domain" {
  description = "The name of the Active Directory domain, for example `consoto.local`"
}

variable "active_directory_username" {
  description = "The username of an account with permissions to bind machines to the Active Directory Domain"
}

variable "active_directory_password" {
  description = "The password of the account with permissions to bind machines to the Active Directory Domain"
}
```

**Note**: Please ensure to use username as domain\adminusername for the code to run as its expecting username to be domain's username.

Comment: This creates a NEW forest, which is not what I am doing. I am attempting to add a domain controller to an existing forest.

Comment: Hello @RNemeth, Sorry for the confusion, will change code after I test it for existing forest .. but may I know if you have used the username as this format "CORP\Administrator"?

Comment: as the install command expects the username like this

Comment: you can refer : https://pixelrobots.co.uk/2019/03/use-terraform-to-join-a-new-azure-virtual-machine-to-a-domain/ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsdeployment/install-addsdomaincontroller?view=windowsserver2019-ps